# Проблемма с jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Всем привет.

Сайт: [www.bandesign.ru](http://www.bandesign.ru)

Версия JQ: jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

Проблеммы: 
 Через вебвизор яндекс метрики, смотрю на поведение людей на сайте. Так вот, бывает (очень часто) что когда люди заходят в портфолио , нажимают на превью картинку, по центру экрана вылезает квадратик загрузочный от фрейма , но самой загрузки фрейма не происходит, т.е. человек ждет открытия фрейма, а он не открывается, соответственно посетитель после нескольких секунд ожидания кликает безрезультатно по разным частям сайта и закрывает его,идет далее бороздить просторы интернета. Это бывает не у всех, но бывает часто, причину понять не могу. Сам пробовал Оперой, IE, Фаерфоксом, Хромом, с андройда заходил – всё ок. Но такая проблемма была и у меня, потом почему-то отпала...

Посетители, у которых такой глюк вылазиет, заходят с разных браузеров, с разных операционных систем, в разное время суток.

Действия примерно такие: bandesign.ru > Портфолио > Баннеры всех форматов > Нажимаем на любую из квадратных превьюшек. И тут либо безрезультатно ждем загрузки окна фрейма, либо всё открывается как надо (у кого как...).

Грешили сначала на загруз сервера, но после того как отписались хостеру, сомнения пропали, хостер говорит что сайт на мощном сервере и нагрузки на ресурсы не наблюдается.

Всю голову уже изломал, но не могу понять в чем причина.

Comment: >> Версия JQ: jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

??? 

приведите проблемный код здесь, а не на своем сайте.

Comment: мне лично посмотреть ваше резюме мешает как ни странно adblock :)

Comment: Код какого именно элемента?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вынести скрипты вниз и поменять очерёдность т.е. сначала jquery, fancybox, а уже потому все остальные. Может быть какой-то из скриптов не может подгрузиться или делает это слишком долго.

Comment: В каком смысле вниз? По поводу очерёдности понял, сайчас так и есть, в head первым делом идет <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Думаю, что @Genson имел в виду, чтоб подключить JS-скрипты перед закрывающим тегом body. А по поводу вашей проблемы - многое в этом случае зависит от инет. подключения, от веса загружаемого контента (*а у вас там не только изображения, но и flash-ролики*), да и сама библиотека fancybox не такая уж маленькая, я бы задумался о выборе чего-нибудь более компактного.

Comment: @Deonis, да вы правы, именно это я имел ввиду.

Comment: Видимо я поторопился с выводом, скорее всего сама метрика яндекс не видит открытия фрейма. Просил многих людей походить по портфолио, у всех всё работает, вывод один - проблемма у самой метрики.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо я поторопился с выводом, скорее всего сама метрика яндекс не видит открытия фрейма. Просил многих людей походить по портфолио, у всех всё работает, вывод один - проблемма у самой метрики.